# Fullcalendar with events to Select2

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, jquery-select2

having many events to manage, I opted for a select to dissect the events and drop them in the calendar, I made this `<https://jsfiddle.net/max1974/mr5yxe7o/4/>`
but I am faced with 2 problems .....
1 ° Initially the objects in the select drop into the calendar, but then if you select other items from the select the drop stops working.
2 ° while I drop the object from the mouse disappears and reappears only when I release it.
Could you help me please.

Comment: For problem 1 I faced a similar problem at work and it is because Select2 recreates all the nodes when you select new items or remove items, try to inspect with developer tools and you will see every <li> for Select2 elements recreated in the DOM when selecting or removing elements. We weren't able to understand what happened and a colleague (senior developer) showed us this behavior.

Comment: For problem 2 it's the relative position of the element inside the Select2.
In your fiddle I have solved both problems, but there is a side effect. When changing position to absolute the element is not exactly below the mouse pointer.

Comment: FYI this question is technically off-topic and could be closed by moderators. _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**_. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See also the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Please see my complete working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gq8eofyL/

You have to use helper() function to clone the element object inside select2 and avoid relative position hiding the element outside the select2 main `<span>`.
Like in this example:

```
helper: function(){
    return '<li class="select2-selection__choice ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">'+$(this).attr('title')+'</li>';
}});
```

In addition, use Select2 events: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events
in order to re-initialize draggables when Select2 recreates the elements, everytime you select/remove the elements (see my comment1 above):

```
function initSelectDraggable(){
$("ul.select2-selection__rendered li").each(function(){
    $(this).data('event', {
      title: $.trim($(this).text()),
      stick: true 
    });
   $(this).draggable({
     
    
      revert: true,     
      revertDuration: 0,
      
      
      helper: function()
            {
                return '<li class="select2-selection__choice ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">'+$(this).attr('title')+'</li>';
            }
    });
     
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it works great, now the problem remains that when I drop the event I lose data-id, data-num that I would need to save them in the DB and the event remains blue in the calendar instead of the chosen color.
Thanks again to everyone  jsfiddle.net/max1974/bmqdax0f/57/

Comment: Ok, but this is another question. In the original fiddle you didn't have colors and the requirement to use data-id and data-num.
In addition, please accept my answer if it is ok.